# Disable ability click to remove selected item on VueTreeselect

Tags: vuejs2, vue-treeselect

I'm using the VueTreeselect but the library does not support any prop to disable the ability click to deselect a selected option. I have a tooltip that wraps each selected option that's why i can't use the `pointer-events: none;`.I can't even add a click handler to "value-label" slot Can anyone show me a way to disable the click but still can hover

Below is my code

```
<treeselect :multiple="true" :options="options" :flat="true" v-model="selectedItems":backspaceRemoves="false">
  <div slot="value-label" slot-scope="{ node }">
    <el-tooltip :content="node.raw.label" placement="bottom" :disabled="node.raw.label < 10">
      <span>{{node.raw.label}}</span>
    </el-tooltip>
  </div>
</treeselect>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue `treeselect` has [Disable Item Selection](https://vue-treeselect.js.org/#disable-item-selection).

For this case, I use function to change the value of `isDisabled` to **true**, so the item will disable, but still showing the tooltip.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/XWOrzQQ)

Comment: But the value is disabled on dropdown how can we deselect it?

Comment: *"Can anyone show me a way to disable the click but still can hover"*. What do you mean by this? I'm sorry, but It seems I misunderstood your question. I though you need to disable the selected value and prevent it to diselect it but the tooltip will still showing. Maybe, better to clarify your question and provide a draft of the output you want to achieve.

Comment: As you can see on my above code, i wrap an treeslect tag by an el-tooltip element (to show full text because i limit each tag's length). But i only want the hover event to be triggered but not the click. If i put ```pointer-events: none;``` the tooltip hover will not active too. The library does not provide a way to disable the click on each tag to deselect feature

Comment: *But the value is disabled on dropdown how can we deselect it?* , *But i only want the hover event to be triggered but not the click.*, **I don't still quite understand the question. Why you need ```pointer-events: none;``` but also you need to disselect the selected item? How you can click the item if you disable the click?? Please clarify it. Making a work  around as well as the image of the output may help a lot.**